# PHP Downloader not downloading?

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I am working on a php downloader and it worked one moment then it did not.

I put my code in multiple error checkers all came out with nothing.

My Code:

```
    <html>
     <title>Downloading...</title>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- Optional theme -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Cosmic Downloads By Cosmic Web Services</div>
     <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Your File Is Downloading...</h1>
      <br>
      <div class="progress">

       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">

    <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>

   </html>

    <?php
    $fullPath = $_GET['url'];
    if($fullPath) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
       $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
       switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; "); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-type:application/zip");
        header("Content-type:application/msword");
        header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        header("Content-type:image/gif");
        header("Content-type:image/png");
        header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
        header("Content-type:image/jpg");
        header("Content-type:image/ico");
        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    if($fsize) {//checking if file size exist
      header("Content-length: $fsize");
    }
    readfile($fullPath);
    exit;
    }
    ?>
```

[image: The page]

I am running it on a chromebook.

If you want to test it out: [click here](http://cosmicsearch.org/download.php?url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Ull.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: why is all that html being echo'ed?

Comment: Why are you sending all those headers?

Comment: For the download load bar and Bootstrap.

Comment: I could have done that better but, for now I will keep it that way for now

Comment: judging but the unreadable characters your browser is showing under the title i presume that your browser is trying to open the file rather than download it, try the browser settings .

Comment: OK but it worked 5 minutes ago and no code changes or setting changes but, i will try

Comment: This is an old style code (php 3/4 age) ;) read how to use switch case.

Comment: You can't output HTML plus the file contents. You have to force a page to open and in that new page include only your php code.

Comment: And you need to include more case statements and send the correct header for each file type.

Comment: I just added the HTML echo stuff because, I thought that somehow may fix it

Comment: Can I have sample code if possible or what to change?

Comment: @arodebaugh No you have to remove it do force the file to download.

Comment: so remove the HTML echo code to force to download or am I miss understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97687/discussion-between-arodebaugh-and-andrew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (warning: I haven't tested it):

```
<?php
$fullPath = $_GET['url'];
if($fullPath) {
$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
switch ($ext) {
    case "pdf":
    header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fullPath).'"');
    break;
    default:
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fullPath).'"');
}
if($fsize) {//checking if file size exist
  header("Content-length: $fsize");
}
readfile($fullPath);
exit;
}
?>
```